# How to write beforeSomeTests in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Learning JS, wondering is it possible in Protractor to do something like

```
before Test1,3,5,7,9,11 etc(function(){
  browser.get('http://192.168.1.117:7777/#/route1');
});
```

and

```
before Test2,4,6,8,10 etc(function(){
  browser.get('http://192.168.1.117:7777/#/route2');
});
```

Or the only way to do *before* is

```
beforeEach(function(){
  browser.get('http://192.168.1.117:7777/#/route');
});
```

Don't wanna write `browser.get` every time, but can't use `beforeEach` cause it's 2 routes, not 1. Excuse me, if my question is ordinary, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i have understood from above question is that you have two different baseUrls and need to use one for a group of test cases and other for remaining test cases.

If I'm right, then answer is "You DON'T have such option". You can do either of following alternative solutions:

1. Divide the test cases into Groups(say describe block here). The test cases which needs to run one first baseUrl, keep them all in one describe block

   ```
   describe('group of test cases which uses route1 url', function(){
       //you can use beforeEach and/or beforeAll
       beforeEach(function(){
           browser.get("http://baseUrl1/route1");   
       }) 

       beforeAll(function() {
           browser.get("http://baseUrl1/route1");   
       }) 

       it('test case1', function(){

       });

       it('test case2', function(){

       });

       it('test case3', function(){

       });

   });
   ```

   Then another suite, could be in same file:

   ```
   describe('group of test cases which uses route2 url',function(){
       //you can use beforeEach and/or beforeAll
       beforeEach(function(){
           browser.get("http://baseUrl2/route2");   
       }) 

       beforeAll(function() {
           browser.get("http://baseUrl2/route2");   
       })

       it('test case1', function(){

       });

       it('test case2', function(){

       });

       it('test case3', function(){

       });


   });
   ```
2. Try with "Using Multiple Browsers in the Same Test" http://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-setup

Answer (score 2):

You should just probably organize your tests in specs accordingly:

```
describe('all tests', function() {
  describe('route 1 tests', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('route1');
    });
    ...
  });

  describe('route 2 tests', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('route2');
    });
    ...
  });
});
```